# Bash command with multiple pipe is providing random output

Tags: bash, shell

Could someone help explaining the below behavior of multiple piped (|) command in shell:

Scenario 1:

echo 1 > t2.txt | echo 2 > t2.txt | echo 3 > t2.txt | echo 4 > t2.txt && cat t2.txt

I was expecting the output of the above command to be '4' (as echo 4 > t2.txt was the last input to txt file) but the actual output was '1'.

Scenario 2:

echo 1 > t2.txt |  touch t2.txt | echo 4 > t2.txt && cat t2.txt

The above command sometimes provide output as 1 and sometimes 4

Here is a basic script to count the outcome:

> result0 && i=0; while [ $i -lt 1000 ]; do echo 1 >test | echo 2 >test| echo 3 >test ; cat test >> result0;  ((i++)); done &&  sort <result0 | uniq -c
> Output:

```
992 1
  8 3
```

Any explanation about this randomness?

Comment: Pipeline components are ran asynchronously. You're running into a race condition by opening `t2.txt` for writing in four different subshells at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour can be better observed with -x set for debugging:

Scenario 1

```
set -x;echo 1 > t2.txt | touch t2.txt | echo 4 > t2.txt && cat t2.txt
+ set -x
+ touch t2.txt
+ echo 4
+ echo 1
+ cat t2.txt
1
```

Since you are piping command through separate sub shells, the "end result" will be dependant on which sub shell finishes first.

Scenario2

```
set -x;echo 1 > t2.txt | touch t2.txt | echo 4 > t2.txt && cat t2.txt
+ set -x
+ touch t2.txt
+ echo 4
+ echo 1
+ cat t2.txt 
4
```

Comment: Thanks @Raman Sailopal for explaining.

Comment: No problem. If the solution helps. Please up vote it and accept.